# How can I create new linux screen without using root but with python started as root

Tags: python, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, arm64

My code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
import time
import os

isBungeeCord = False
serverPath = "/TheJebScream"
powerPIN = 3
screenName = "minecraft"

def startListening(GPIO_PIN, screen):
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.FALLING)

    subprocess.call(["screen", "-Rd", screen, "-X", "stuff", 'stop\r'], shell=False)
    while str(subprocess.Popen(["screen", "-ls"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines()).find(screen) != -1:
        time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.call(["screen", "-X", "-S", screen, "kill"], shell=False)
    subprocess.call(["sudo", "shutdown", "-h", "now"], shell=False)


def startMC(screen):
    subprocess.call(["screen", "-dmS", screen, "java", "-Xmx4G", "-Xms4G", "-jar", "server.jar"], shell=False)

os.chdir(serverPath)
startMC(screenName)
startListening(powerPIN, screenName)
```

That problem is in the function startMC. It just doesnt work with root but I need to run that python program as root becose I need to shutdown my rpi and it only works with root.

Comment: you can use a different user with `sudo -u <myuser> <cmd>`

Comment: So I need to create another user for that?

Comment: I added that thing with new user and it didnt work.

Comment: So it works only with "screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff stop\r" and "screen -ls" but not with the one in my function startMC and I still dont know why